# How to assign control's position?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have xml file created in other asp.net project,these file include some controls and their attributes.i need to show those controls on my mvc project,

xml file format may be like below.

```
<div style='left:84px;top: 50px;' ><input id='Text1' type='text' value='Mr.Temp'/></div>
<div style='left:8px;top: 50px; position: fixed;' >Name</div>
<div style='left:84px;top: 650px;' ><input id='Text1' type='text' value='30'/></div>
<div style='left:8px;top: 65px; position: fixed;' >Age</div>
<div style='left:84px;top: 90px;' ><input id='Text1' type='text' value='Singapore'/></div>
<div style='left:8px;top: 90px;' >Address</div>
```

i need to show these controls depend on their type and location like this.

Name    Mr.Temp
Age     30
Address Singapore

So,i read xml file and write ,my problem is i can create controls based on their type,but i don't know how to 
assign their position correctly?Their old location can't use any more because mine is asp.net mvc project.

Give me right way,please.

regards

Indi

Comment: It looks like applying `position:absolute` to these elements would make it work. Then you can replace inputs with labels. All can be done with jQuery, but if you want details, sample input and sample output would be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using xslt?  Then you can write rules around all that.

Or, if you don't want to use xslt, then consider using jQuery and write your own plugin to look through your xml and transform that to html.

**edit**

Well with a plug in you can check out how to write a jQuery plugin [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Essentially what you'll be doing is giving the xml to the plugin and then the plugin will generate the html for you.

It's a bit too involved for here but you can "each()" on the div, store the first one, then the second and generate html for the pair then move to the next two.

```
$(xmlDoc).find("div").each(function(){
  //this will get each div. now you need to create html for each and return the 
  //whole as a string to be rendered.
});
```